# Setting up GDAL via buildout on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-10.04, buildout, gdal

I'm trying to install GDAL-1.9.0 under Ubuntu 10.04 via buildout and unfortunately get a very strange error.

```
python setup.py build
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 75, in <module>
    from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 13, in <module>
    from site import USER_BASE, USER_SITE
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/parts/buildout/site.py", line 601, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/parts/buildout/site.py", line 583, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/parts/buildout/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/parts/buildout/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/parts/buildout/site.py", line 235, in getuserbase
    from sysconfig import get_config_var
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
make[2]: *** [build] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/tmpY7oYvSbuildout-gdal/gdal-1.9.0/swig/python'
make[1]: *** [build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/tmpY7oYvSbuildout-gdal/gdal-1.9.0/swig'
make: *** [swig-modules] Error 2
gdal: cmmi failed: /tmp/tmpY7oYvSbuildout-gdal
While:
  Installing gdal.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1805, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 584, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1297, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.5-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 113, in install
    self.build()
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.5-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 196, in build
    self.cmmi(dest)
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.5-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 222, in cmmi
    system("make")
  File "/home/student/geoserv_new/geoportal2/trunk/eggs/zc.recipe.cmmi-1.3.5-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 34, in system
    raise SystemError("Failed", c)
SystemError: ('Failed', 'make')
```

Here is my buildout.cfg part of gdal:

```
[gdal]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/gdal-1.9.0.tar.gz
extra_options = 
    --with-python
    --with-geos=${geos:location}/bin/geos-config
```

Even more strange that when I'm going to python2.7 shell and try import sysconfig. Everything is working fine. Any suggestion about this?

Thanks,
Sergey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you tested it in the 'python2.7' shell.

This:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py",
```

Implies that buildout is running in python 2.6.

Is sysconfig available in your python2.6 environment, or are you running buildout under the wrong version?